# Symfony 2.1 - Getting Session ID

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

While trying to migrate from Symfony 2.0 to 2.1, I've found some interesting issue.

I cannot get the native session id, even in the plain, just downloaded Symfony 2.1 copy.

```
/**
 * @Route("/sess")
 */
public function sessionAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    return new Response($session->getId());
}
```

Did something changed significantly there?

Comment: Apparently, I get the session ID, when I put `$session->start();` before the return `Response()`. That's kinda odd to me - in 2.0, session was started automatically (I think).

Comment: Moreover, if I remove the `start()` method and use `$session->set()`, it works fine. The problem is - I don't want to set any session variables, just get the current session_id (most likely without calling the `start()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this document](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) (under **app/config/config.yml** section)

In Symfony 2.1 session is always started on-demand. So I'd say what you are seeing is the normal behavior. You need to start the session explicitly before you can get the session ID. I've not checked but maybe setting the first variable also starts the session this is because it works after you call set().

Comment: You have a broken link